# What is the zero of a group ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a finite group and R a commutative unital ring. Let RG be the corresponding group ring. My question is, does it follow that 0g = 0$1_G$ for all g in G (where $1_G$ means the identity element of the group)?

On wikipedia, it reads 'The additive identity element is of course zero'. I take that to mean that the additive identity element is 0$1_G$, which certainly has the zero property of x + 0 = x for all x. I believe the elements  0g also have this property, that is why I'm starting to think 0g = 0$1_G$ for all g in G. However, I have not been able to prove this.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to think of the group ring (in my opinion) as the set of *maps with finite support* (that is, only finitely often nonzero) from $G$ to $R$. Intuitively, such a map $f$ is a $R$-linear combination of elements of $G$.

The zero of the group ring is then the zero map: the map $g\mapsto 0$.

When we write an element of the group ring as "$r_1g_1+...+r_ng_n$" (with the $g_i$s distinct) what we're describing is the map $f$ such that $f(g_i)=r_i$ and $f(h)=0$ for $h\not\in \{g_1, . . . , g_n\}$. So in particular, "$01_R$" and "$0r$" (for $r\in R$ arbitrary) denote the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Any module $M$ has an additive identity that is equal to $0x$ for any $x\in M$. This is because
$$0x=(0+0)x=0x+0x$$
so
$$0x=0x-0x=0$$
It thus makes the most sense to treat $0$ as a "module thing." It behaves the same way in any module, and there's no virtue in writing it as $01_G$ or as $0x$ for any other element $x$.